Cannot see the uploaded files on web3.storage
I’m building a website using Next js that allows users to upload files to IPFS using web3.storage. I’ve followed their documentation (https://web3.storage/docs/w3up-client/)) thoroughly, and the account creation and file uploads are working correctly, and I’m receiving the CID as expected.
However, when I check the files on Web3.storage, they don’t appear.
I tried many times with different accounts on web3.storage but the problem is still there.
Note that I am using their free payment plan.
Could anyone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you!

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Try this:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/YOURCID

Also this might take some time to load.
